How can I batch process multiple .npy files in Python for motion capture data preprocessing?
I am working on a project where I need to preprocess multiple motion capture files stored in .npy format. I am able to load and preprocess individual files, but I am facing difficulties when trying to process multiple files in a directory. The goal is to iterate through all the .npy files, apply preprocessing, and store the results for each file.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
import os
import numpy as np

motion_dir = "path/to/motion_files"
motion_files = [f for f in os.listdir(motion_dir) if f.endswith('.npy')]

processed_data = []

for file_path in motion_files:
    try:
        # Load the .npy file
        data = np.load(os.path.join(motion_dir, file_path))
        
        # Example of preprocessing: Normalization
        data = (data - np.mean(data)) / np.std(data)
        processed_data.append(data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {file_path}: {e}")

The issue I am facing is that I can load multiple .npy files correctly, but I cannot preprocess them all together. When I load the files, the data appears to be stored as a single vector or list, which makes it difficult to apply the preprocessing (such as normalization) correctly.
Is there a more efficient way to handle loading and processing multiple .npy  files in Python?
Are there best practices for handling .npy file formats in one workflow?
How can I preprocess these multiple .npy files efficiently while preserving the structure of the data?

Sounds like you're trying to replicate the functionality of a dask array.   Are you somehow restricted to iterating over .npy files due to hardware or API constraints?

In any case, a full error trace and/or current output, and expected output (at least data shapes and sizes) would be needed to effectively troubleshoot.

as per @DanielF, show all your code, read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , then edit your question so folks can provide relevant feedback.
